# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string - using a While Loop

Tags: python

I'm doing the old 99 bottles song and trying to do it using a While loop, to help me continue to better learn that loop type.

I'm wondering why I would be getting a TypeError when in my code below and what arguments exactly I'm missing?

Here is my code:

```
# Get number of beers
bottles = int(raw_input("How many bottles of beer? "))

# return invalid response
if bottles < 1:
    print "That's not a good number"

    if bottles == 1:
        s1 = "bottle" 
        s2 = "bottles" 

    elif bottles == 2:
        s1 = "bottles" 
        s2 = "bottles" 

# sing verses
while bottles > 0:
    print "%d %s of beer on the wall," % bottles, s1
    print "%d %s of beer." % bottles, s1
    print "You take one down, pass it around,"
    print "%d %s of beer on the wall." % (bottles - 1), s2
    print
    bottles -= 1
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "beer.py", line 47, in <module>
          print "%d %s of beer on the wall," % bottles, s1
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I've tried using parenthesis around the "bottles, s1" after the %, but still doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `(bottles, s1)` works for me.

Comment: What if the input for bottles is 10. Where does `s1` and `s2` get defined?

Comment: Your code will generate a NameError if you set `bottles` to anything larger than 2, since in that case neither of your if/elif will execute.  You should change the elif to an if.  Also it looks like you have an indentation problem.  The if/elif should not be under the `if bottles < 1`.

Comment: And it also would never update your `s1` and `s2` strings since they only get evaluated once from the user input. The while loop will just spin until it'd done. You would need to move them inside of the `while` loop so they get set properly each time.

Comment: I guess I'm still just confused as to how I should be defining my conditions for `s1` and `s2` and then how they're supposed to be called on in the song.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to specify multiple arguments as tuple, eg

```
print "%d %s of beer on the wall," % (bottles, s1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Along with specifying those arguments as a tuple, I also realized that 1.) the `While` loop was in the wrong place, should have been below the corner case  2.) I didn't have an `else` clause to allow for numbers higher than 2. Cheers.